# Add extra field to serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I need to add an extra field to serializer. I have below django serialzer

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 8363,
      "name": "test10",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 8360,
      "name": "check",
      "description": "edew"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to add a field, for example, let us call it as `new_field`.
How can we make this possible? The structure I am expecting is below.

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 8363,
      "name": "test10",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 8360,
      "name": "check",
      "description": "edew"
    }
  ],
  "new_field": "New Field Value"
}
```

The serialzer will look like given below.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id, name, description')
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the serializer itself?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you use ModelSerializer so your code looks like:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

to add new field you should do something like:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    new_field = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['count', 'next', ... , 'new_field]
```

Comment: Hi @Vlad. I appreciate your comment. With the answer you have provided, it will add new_field to the `id, name, description`. What I want `new_field` is to be added outside this fields. If you look at the serializer I added `new_field` as a common field for all.

Comment: ah, didnt understand, that you use pagination, my bad. I will add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    new_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_new_field(self,obj):
        ...codes 
        return new_field
```

this is how you can add new_field

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your comment. With the answer you have provided, it will add new_field to the `id, name, description`. What I want `new_field` is to be added outside this fields. If you look at the serializer I added `new_field` as a common field for all.

Answer (score 0):

To add extra field to paginated response, you basicly need to create custom pagination class

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    
    # 
    # Some params like page_size 
    #

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data,
            'new_field': 'new_value'                
        })
```

Then you can set this serializer as DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles

or just use it in your view:

```
class MyView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginator = CustomPagination()
    results = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
    serializer = MySerializer(results, many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```